# imageresizing.net resource not found issue

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer

I 'm currently using imageresizer.dll ver3.3.3 in my ASP.NET MVC 4 web 
project hosted on IIS7.5. I have included the imageresizer.mvc.dll in the 
bin folder and added the mvc shim plugin.

Everything works properly in my local machine. But in production machine I 
'm facing resource not found issue. The production machine also has ASP.NET 
MVC 4, IIS7.5 and the bin directory contains both dlls and web.config file 
is as follows:

In the production machine. 
1. When I execute the image request with .ashx, I get the resource not 
found exception. 
2. To verify if the image really exists, I removed the .ashx and the 
image was loaded without issues. So something I 'm missing on imageresizing 
part in my production machine. 
3. I tried to diagnose the issue by executing /resizer.debug.ashx but 
here too I get resource not found exception. 
4. I tried omitting the .ashx extension but with width paramter in the querystring. The image size isn't affected.

I 'm totally unsure what are my next steps to address this issue. Can anyone
please guide me what I'm missing?

Thanks and Regards, 
G Hemant

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I doubt that you are running in Integrated Mode on the production server. You're probably running on Classic Mode and [failed to follow the installation instructions](http://imageresizing.net/docs/install#manual)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the installation instructions to the best of my ability and I had the same issue as you regarding the /resizer.debug

I am not using MVC as a whole; however, I am using routing and have a RegisterRoutes method in my Application_Start section of the global.asax.

This line, added to the RegisterRoutes method solved my issue with not being able to get access to resizer.debug.ashx:

```
  routes.Ignore("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}"); //ignore ashx files
```

Now I have access from Cassini as well as iis7.